# finding the number of integer points under a triangle, square and circle

Tags: math, geometry

for circle i have tried to check for all points within radius distance from center.For  square, i test for all points from bottom-left-corner to upper-right-corner and for triangle i  test the signs of determinants as suggested [here](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110614030208AATF7aU). I get correct answer while i enter individual values i.e either 1 cirlce or 1 square or 1 triangle , but not when there are >1 of them. E.g for the case:

```
C 10 10 3
S 9 8 4
T 7 9 10 8 8 10
```

where C is circle, S is square and T is triangle,and (10,10) is center of circle with radius 3. (9,8) is the left-most corner of square of side 4 and (7,9),(10,8) and (8,10) are the three vertices of the triangle , the total distinct points covered by them is 34 but i am getting 37.

Here's what i've tried:

```
typedef pair<int,int> point;
set<point>myset;
set<point>::iterator it;

int findDeter(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int x0,int y0)
{
int ret = x1*(y2-y0)-y1*(x2-x0)+(x2*y0-x0*y2)
         -x2*(y1-y0)+y2*(x1-x0)-(x1*y0-x0*y1)
         +x0*(y1-y2)-y0*(x1-x2)+(x1*y2-x2*y1);
return ret;
}
bool sameSign(int x, int y)
{
if(x==0||y==0)
return true;
    return (x >= 0) ^ (y < 0);
}
int main()
{
int t,i,j,k,n;
int x,y,r,x1,y1,len;
int xmax,ymax,xmin,ymin;
int D1,D2,D3;
int ax,ay,bx,by,cx,cy;
char shape,dump;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
{
    myset.clear();
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&dump);
        scanf("%c",&shape);
        if(shape=='C')
        {
            scanf("%d %d %d",&x,&y,&r);
            for(j=x;j<=x+r;j++)
            {
                for(k=y;k<=y+r;k++)
                {
                    point p(j,k);
                    myset.insert(p);
                }
            }
            for(j=x-r;j<x;j++)
            {
                for(k=y-r;k<y;k++)
                {
                    point p(j,k);
                    myset.insert(p);
                }
            }   

        }
        else if(shape=='S')
        {
            scanf("%d %d %d",&x1,&y1,&len);
            for(j=x1;j<=x1+len;j++)
            {
                for(k=y1;k<=y1+len;k++)
                {
                    point p(j,k);
                    myset.insert(p);
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //printf("here\n");
            scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",&ax,&ay,&bx,&by,&cx,&cy);
            /*a1=ax;a2=ay;
            b1=bx;b2=by;
            c1=cx;c2=cy;*/
            xmax = max(ax,max(bx,cx));
            ymax = max(ay,max(by,cy));
            xmin = min(ax,min(bx,cx));
            ymin = min(ay,min(by,cy));
            /*for each point P check if sum(the determinants PAB,PAC and PBC have the same signs)*/
            for(j=xmin;j<=xmax;j++)
            {
                for(k=ymin;k<=ymax;k++)
                {
                    D1 = findDeter(ax,ay,bx,by,j,k);
                    //printf("D1 : %d\n",D1);
                    D2 = findDeter(bx,by,cx,cy,j,k);
                    //printf("D2 : %d\n",D2);
                    D3 = findDeter(cx,cy,ax,ay,j,k);
                    //printf("D3 : %d\n",D3);
                    if(sameSign(D1,D2)&&sameSign(D2,D3)&&sameSign(D1,D3))
                    {
                        //printf("here\n");
                        point p(j,k);
                        myset.insert(p);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    printf("%d\n",myset.size());
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: And which points do you find that aren't in the triangle? Doesn't that point to a bug?

Comment: You should check the return value from scanf, it could be failing to parse the correct number of values. Also, what is dump?

Comment: @Angelom: the dump is reading the newline character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After refactoring your code heavily so that it was clearer to me what is going on - I'd say the error is in the circle code. I've included the complete refactored code below but the troublesome section amount s to this:

```
struct Circle
{
   int x;
   int y;
   int r;

   void add_covered_points( set<points> & pts ) const
   {
      for(int j=x;j<=x+r;j++)
      {
         for(int k=y;k<=y+r;k++)
         {
            pts.insert(point(j,k));
         }
      }
      for(int j=x-r;j<x;j++)
      {
         for(int k=y-r;k<y;k++)
         {
            pts.insert(point(j,k));
         }
      }  
   }
};
```

This seems to add points from two rectangular sections, one above and the other below the center of the circle. I'd expect the code to look more like this:

```
   void add_covered_points( set<points> & pts ) const
   {
      for(int j=-r;j<=+r;j++)
      {
         for(int k=-r;k<=+r;k++)
         {
            if (j*j + k*k < r*r )
            {
              pts.insert(point(x+j,x+k));
            }
         }
      } 
   }
```

Heres the complete refactored case for your reference

```
typedef pair<int,int> point;


int findDeter(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int x0,int y0)
{
int ret = x1*(y2-y0)-y1*(x2-x0)+(x2*y0-x0*y2)
         -x2*(y1-y0)+y2*(x1-x0)-(x1*y0-x0*y1)
         +x0*(y1-y2)-y0*(x1-x2)+(x1*y2-x2*y1);
return ret;
}
bool sameSign(int x, int y)
{
if(x==0||y==0)
return true;
    return (x >= 0) ^ (y < 0);
}

struct Circle
{
   int x;
   int y;
   int r;

   void add_covered_points( set<points> & pts ) const
   {
      for(int j=x;j<=x+r;j++)
      {
         for(int k=y;k<=y+r;k++)
         {
            pts.insert(point(j,k));
         }
      }
      for(int j=x-r;j<x;j++)
      {
         for(int k=y-r;k<y;k++)
         {
            pts.insert(point(j,k));
         }
      }  
   }
};

struct Square
{
  int x1,y1,len;
  void add_covered_points( set<points> & pts ) const
  {
     for(int j=x1;j<=x1+len;j++)
     {
        for(int k=y1;k<=y1+len;k++)
        {
           myset.insert(point(j,k));
        }
     }
  }
};

struct Triangle
{
  int ax,ay,bx,by,cx,cy;
  void add_covered_points( set<points> & pts ) const
  {
     int xmax = max(ax,max(bx,cx));
     int ymax = max(ay,max(by,cy));
     int xmin = min(ax,min(bx,cx));
     int ymin = min(ay,min(by,cy));

     /*for each point P check if sum(the determinants PAB,PAC and PBC have the same signs)*/
     for(int j=xmin;j<=xmax;j++)
     {
       for(int k=ymin;k<=ymax;k++)
       {
          int D1 = findDeter(ax,ay,bx,by,j,k);
          int D2 = findDeter(bx,by,cx,cy,j,k);
          int D3 = findDeter(cx,cy,ax,ay,j,k);

          if(sameSign(D1,D2)&&sameSign(D2,D3)&&sameSign(D1,D3))
          {
            pts.insert(point(j,k));
          }
        }
     }
  }
};


int main()
{
set<point>myset;
int t;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
{
    myset.clear();
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        char dump;
        char shape;
        scanf("%c",&dump);
        scanf("%c",&shape);
        if(shape=='C')
        {
            Circle c;
            scanf("%d %d %d",&c.x,&c.y,&c.r);
            c.add_covered_points( myset );
        }
        else if(shape=='S')
        {
            Square s;
            scanf("%d %d %d",&s.x1,&s.y1,&s.len);
            s.add_covered_points( myset );
        }
        else
        {
            Triangle t;
            int ax,ay,bx,by,cx,cy;
            scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",&t.ax,&t.ay,&t.bx,&t.by,&t.cx,&t.cy);
            t.add_covered_points( myset );
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks but this code for circle does not give the correct value for a case like: C 5 5 2 which is 13 rather than 9

Comment: @pranay Why don't you plot the points that it lists as interior and compare those with the points you expect to be interior? How do the shapes compare?

Answer (score 1):

[Pick's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) is suitable for counting integer points in the interior of simple polygons with integer vertices.

[Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html) we can see solution for circles.